# Unable to locate element error is coming in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am using the latest `webdriver` version. Below is the `webdriver` code which i have written

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
       WebElement providerprofile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='provider-namebox']//a[@href='#provider-detail?anthony-firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch']"));
 providerprofile.click();
```

And below is the HTML Snippet

```
<div class="col-sm-12 inner-provider clearfix">
<a href="#provider-detail?anthony--firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch">
<span class="col-xs-5 col-sm-12 image-box">
<img class="img-circle" alt="" src="images/provider-image.png"/>
</span>
</a>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-12 mobile-showBox">
<div class="provider-namebox">
<a href="#provider-detail?anthony-firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch">
<span class="nowrap">
<h2>Anthony </h2>
</span>
<span class="nowrap">
<h2>Firilas</h2>
, MD
</span>
</a>
<h3> N/A </h3>
</div>
```

Now when I am running the above `webdriver` code it is giving me error as
`"Unable to locate element "`.

Xpath which i have used for above HTML : `//div[@class='provider-namebox']//a[@href='#provider-detail?anthony-firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch']`

Even though with the same xpath it is identifying in firebug and firepath

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the issue was after i was performing the search option using webdriver the webdriver was not able to locate the element it was happening because my xpath was somehow not unique because of the dynamic values which was coming and their xpaths were same as my xpath so i have use forward sibling method to identify the particular element to go ahead in identifying the element.

Comment: Prefer this as a comment - and please explain for future readers what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code to identify the element.

```
WebElement providerprofile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='provider-namebox']/a"));
```

Comment: Still getting the below error    "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='provider-namebox']/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 187 milliseconds"

Comment: @Akash First make sure that page is completely loaded before finding the element(you can use JavaScript to find page load status). Next try to identify the `div` element only using classname. If you are unable to identify the `div` tag, then verify whether `div` element is present in any frame. If you able to find `div` element successfully, use the syntax I provided to find the link element.

Comment: Did you verify whether your element is present in any Frame?

Comment: Are you able to identify only `div` element successfully using classname?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is "Unable to locate element", it is possible that the element has not loaded in the assigned period of time. Additionally, if the href is unique and not "dynamic", you can search only for the href. Try the following code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);        
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@href='#provider-detail?anthony-firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch']")));
```

With the "wait" command, the test will wait for 60 seconds before exiting with an error. Once the element is located it will continue immediately. If you still receive the same error, it is possible that href is not unique. Maybe you can try by class name...

Comment: Still getting the below error   "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@href='#provider-detail?anthony-firilas&U2FsdGVkX181p0qdh48AoV8B1OV7voTYsNsYgSWYsg0=&Ashley River Family Physicians@South Carolina@@@@@@@@@28.6667@77.2167&standardsearch']
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35' "

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the href is always the same?

Comment: It is not a good practice to find an element by href. Since the element is not found in 60secs it is definitely not loading. What are you trying to click? To make sure the page is fully loaded try this : `ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
   public Boolean apply(WebDriver _driver) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) _driver).executeScript(
      "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
   }
  };` Also can you test on some other element on you page to check that the page is loading correctly...

Comment: Etiene yes you are right the href is never been the same just now i have observed but now what to do i have tried with your code above but still it was giving the same error

Comment: And the scenario is like i have to give some input values in the drop down and then click on the match button and then at the bottom of the search box few doctors profile will come in the same page only and out of those recommended ones i need to click one of them.....

Comment: Yes of course if the href is different all the time, the element will never be found that way. If you are not succesful also by classname, there is another way to check for text, For example, in the above case you can search for "Anthony". Try this code : `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);
  
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Anthony')]")));
  
  element.click();` You should be able to work. However the text will need to be updated, meaning if you are not searching for "Anthony" you have to change that.